# How to add custom column of custom table field or module to sales order admin grid in magento2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, magento-2.0, order-grid

I am trying to add my custom table field  to order grid **but its not working fine for sales order grid but its working fine product grid** so below are the code adding column to sales order grid and product grid

**i feel problem is in type name** 
for product i gave

```
 <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider">
```

**working fine** 
but for order grid i gave

```
 <type name="sales_order_grid_data_source">
```

**but sales order grid through error**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider::addField() in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\module-ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column.php on line 116
```

below are the code for ading my custom field to order and product grid

1. app\code\Sugarcode\Test\etc\adminhtml\di.xml

   ```
   <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="addFieldStrategies" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="title" xsi:type="object">Sugarcode\Test\Ui\DataProvider\Test\AddTitleFieldToCollection</item>
           </argument>
           <argument name="addFilterStrategies" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="title" xsi:type="object">Sugarcode\Test\Ui\DataProvider\Test\AddTitleFilterToCollection</item>
           </argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
   <type name="sales_order_grid_data_source">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="addFieldStrategies" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="title" xsi:type="object">Sugarcode\Test\Ui\DataProvider\Test\AddTitleFieldToOrderCollection</item>
           </argument>
           <argument name="addFilterStrategies" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="title" xsi:type="object">Sugarcode\Test\Ui\DataProvider\Test\AddTitleFilterToOrderCollection</item>
           </argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
   ```
2. app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml

   ```
   <columns name="sales_order_columns">
       <column name="title">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Titles</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">75</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>       
   </columns>
   ```
3. app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml

   ```
   <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
       <column name="title">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Titles</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">75</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>       
   </columns>
   ```

4 app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Ui\DataProvider\Test\AddTitleFieldToCollection.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Ui\DataProvider\Test;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface;

/**
 * Class AddQuantityFieldToCollection
 */
class AddTitleFieldToCollection implements AddFieldToCollectionInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addField(Collection $collection, $field, $alias = null)
    {
        $collection->joinField(
            'title',
            'testtable', //tablename
            'title',  //field
            'id=entity_id', //join condition
            '1', // condition 
            'left'
        );
    }
}
```

5 app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Ui\DataProvider\Test\AddTitleFieldToOrderCollection.php

```
 <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    namespace Sugarcode\Test\Ui\DataProvider\Test;

    use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
    use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface;

    /**
     * Class AddQuantityFieldToCollection
     */
    class AddTitleFieldToOrderCollection implements AddFieldToCollectionInterface
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function addField(Collection $collection, $field, $alias = null)
        {
            $collection->joinField(
                'title',
                'testtable',
                'title',
                'id=entity_id',
                '1',
                'left'
            );
        }
    }
```

6 app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Ui\DataProvider\Test\AddTitleFilterToCollection.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    namespace Sugarcode\Test\Ui\DataProvider\Test;

    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
    use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
    use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface;

    /**
     * Class AddQuantityFilterToCollection
     */
    class AddTitleFilterToCollection implements AddFilterToCollectionInterface
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function addFilter(Collection $collection, $field, $condition = null)
        {
            if (isset($condition['like'])) {
                $collection->getSelect()->where(
                    AbstractCollection::ATTRIBUTE_TABLE_ALIAS_PREFIX . 'title.title like ?',
                    $condition['like']
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

7 app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Ui\DataProvider\Test\AddTitleFilterToOrderCollection.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    namespace Sugarcode\Test\Ui\DataProvider\Test;

    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
    use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
    use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface;

    /**
     * Class AddQuantityFilterToCollection
     */
    class AddTitleFilterToOrderCollection implements AddFilterToCollectionInterface
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function addFilter(Collection $collection, $field, $condition = null)
        {
            if (isset($condition['like'])) {
                $collection->getSelect()->where(
                    AbstractCollection::ATTRIBUTE_TABLE_ALIAS_PREFIX . 'title.title like ?',
                    $condition['like']
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

can any one help me :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join order grid collection to custom table in Magento2?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91807/how-to-join-order-grid-collection-to-custom-table-in-magento2)

Answer (score 1):

As I see **$addFieldStrategies** property is declared only in [ProductDataProvider](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/ProductDataProvider.php#L25), so it looks to be applicable only for product data providers.

Please check this [article](http://blog.sivaschenko.com/2016/05/magento-2-tutorial-add-column-to-sales.html) for step by step instructions on adding a column to Sales Order Grid.

Comment: Link does not appear to be working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to add a column to Magento's core grids or other grids i.e. sales order.

The possible two ways are

1. using plugin to join on sales order grid collection with other
   tables (see [my answer here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159691/50597))
2. create a column in sales_order_grid table and save values in that column  for an order. (see [Sergey's post](http://blog.sivaschenko.com/2016/05/magento-2-tutorial-add-column-to-sales.html))