# How to join order grid collection to custom table in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I am trying to add a new column to order grid in Magento 2.0. So, i need to do joining to order grid collection. How can I achieve this ? Because, in magento2, the grid uses UI component.

Answer (score 15):

Magento 2 add custom columns to sales order grid,

To join

> Magento\Sales\Order\Grid\Collection

to any table(s), using plugin would be the best option as this does not rely on rewrites and makes code lean.

**Create the plugin in your module's etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <plugin name="sales_order_additional_columns" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugins\AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection" sortOrder="100" disabled="false" />
</type>
```

So, we are intercepting

> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory

because if you take a look at the

> Magento\Sales\etc\di.xml

you would see

> Magento\Sales\Order\Grid\Collection

was injected into

> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory

**Create a Plugin folder and a plugin class in your module**

```
<?php namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugins;

use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as SalesOrderGridCollection;

class AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection
{
    private $messageManager;
    private $collection;

    public function __construct(MessageManager $messageManager,
        SalesOrderGridCollection $collection
    ) {

        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public function aroundGetReport(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $requestName
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($requestName);
        if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
            if ($result instanceof $this->collection
            ) {
                $select = $this->collection->getSelect();
                $select->join(
                    ["soi" => "sales_order_item"],
                    'main_table.entity_id = soi.order_id AND soi.product_type="simple"',
                    array('weight', 'product_type')
                )
                    ->distinct();

                $select->join(
                    ["soa" => "sales_order_address"],
                    'main_table.entity_id = soa.parent_id AND soa.address_type="shipping"',
                    array('email', 'country_id', 'postcode', 'city', 'telephone')
                )
                    ->distinct();
            }

        }
        return $this->collection;
    }
}
```

Here we are observing **around** event of getReport() method.

Copy

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

to your module's scope

> Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

Delete all contents of your copied sales_order_grid.xml as we don't want to override all the contents.

Enter the following code in your module's sales_order_grid.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <columns name="sales_order_columns">

        <!-- sales_order_item weight -->
        <column name="weight">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Weight</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">222</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">right</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <!--<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>-->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <!-- sales_order_item product_type-->
        <column name="product_type">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ProductTypes</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Type</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">232</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">right</item>
                    <!--<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>-->
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <!--<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>-->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <!-- sales_order_address country_id -->
        <column name="country_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">242</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">right</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <!--<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>-->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <!-- sales_order_address post_code -->
        <column name="postcode">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Postcode</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">252</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">right</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <!--<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>-->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <!-- sales_order_address city -->
        <column name="city">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">City</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">252</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">right</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <!--<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>-->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <!-- sales_order_address telephone -->
        <column name="telephone">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Telephone</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">252</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">right</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <!--<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>-->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

    </columns>

</listing>
```

Now, delete cache from var/cache folder or refresh your cache.
You would be able to see your added columns in is sales order grid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that one, my only issue (with Magento 2.2.0) was that I had to add table prefix on lines `["soi" => "sales_order_item"]` and `["soa" => "sales_order_address"]`.

Comment: I thought it was working fine, but it seems to mess with the invoice grid also.. With the module enabled, order ID and status are weirdly empty in the invoice grid.. Any idea on what could be wrong ?

Comment: Thank you for this information, it has helped me add company name. But how would I show billing and shipping information instead of just shipping? I can show 1 or the other but I can't seem to rename 'company' to say 'billing_company' and 'shipping_company' in order to use in sales_order_grid.xml

Comment: Getting errors in CMS Page, CMS Block, Customer and Creditmemo grids when using the plugin class, Please let me know if any alternate solution to modify grid collection.

Comment: What errors can you see for invoice grid and etc?

Comment: Getting errors in CMS Page page_id unknow column

Comment: @Asrar  : Having issue while applying filter on country_id column. Can you please look this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/327312/magento-2-how-to-add-country-id-column-in-sales-order-grid and help me.

Answer (score 9):

When you look at `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb` magento2 itself provide hook operation for your collection.

```
protected function _renderFilters()
{
    if ($this->_isFiltersRendered) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->_renderFiltersBefore(); // Hook for operations before rendering filters

    ....................
}
```

---

So, what you need to do this by just adding in your collection[`NAMESPACE\MODULENAME\Model\ResourceModel\YOUR_CLASSNAME\Grid\Collection`]

```
protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
    $joinTable = $this->getTable('catalog_product_entity_varchar');
    $this->getSelect()->join($joinTable.' as cpev','main_table.entity_id = cpev.entity_id', array('*'));
    parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```

Comment: i need to show my custom table field in order grid in this case ho to show it ?

Comment: @Keyur Shah  Thanks it helps a lot to me.

Comment: Glad to hear that It helps you :) @RohitGoel Keep helps the other community member

Comment: Sure :) @KeyurShah i love to help community  .I am creating a grid without ui  component , can you please tell me how can i add a export feature in that.

Comment: I think you should use UI component feature of Magento 2,  but If its your special need then you can ask a new question for that, someone will give some hint or answer @RohitGoel

Comment: `NAMESPACE\MODULENAME\Model\ResourceModel\YOUR_CLASSNAME\Grid\Collection` does not seem to be used in my case. At least, the `_construct` method (which determines the model and resource model of the collection) does not get called.

Comment: Instead of `_renderFiltersBefore`, you can also override/extend `_initSelect`.

Comment: @KeyurShah can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/296226/77631

Answer (score 3):

In the ui definition xml there is a datasource node similar to this

```
<dataSource name="listing_name_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">UniqueNameGridDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">listing_name_data_source</argument>
```

where `listing_name_data_source` can be defined in your `di.xml` or just reference a class directly. The class itself should extend from `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory` and have as `collections` argument your custom collection. In that collection class's `_initSelect()` method you can join your tables.

Comment: in sales di.xml it showing Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection where that file it self not exits , in that case we can not rewrite plugin or event, o how to do it please check sales di and order grid collection code , i hope that will clear more

Comment: It's defined here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/di.xml#L779 and is a virtual type extending from Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult

Comment: then ho to add join to that class.can you give example code

Comment: here as an example for a join https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/Group/Collection.php#L54 as used in this initSelect https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/Group/Grid/Collection.php#L19

Comment: @KristofatFooman you give a wrong example because it is a virtual type, could you give an example for grid collection defined as virtual type?

Answer (score 3):

I created admin grid which has join of two custom tables. you cannot do this by using virtual type is di.xml, so you need to follow these steps and update your

etc/di.xml,

Model/Resource/Modulename/Collection.php add join in this file,

Model/Resource/Modulename/Grid/Collection.php,

IN your etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="namespace_modulename_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">tablename</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">namespace_modulename_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">namespace_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

IN your Model/Resource/Modulename/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    const YOUR_TABLE = 'tablename';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->_init(
            'Namespace\Modulename\Model\Modulename',
            'Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename'
        );
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('tablename')],
                'main_table.columnname = secondTable.columnname',
                ['columnname1','columnname2','columnname3']
            );
    }
}
?>
```

IN your Model/Resource/Modulename/Grid/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\Resource\Modulename\Collection as ModulenameCollection;

/**
 * Class Collection
 * Collection for displaying grid
 */
class Collection extends ModulenameCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
    /**
     * Resource initialization
     * @return $this
     */
   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $storeManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    /**
     * @return AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * @param AggregationInterface $aggregations
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }


    /**
     * Get search criteria.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Set search criteria.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null
    ) {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * Set total count.
     *
     * @param int $totalCount
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set items list.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: It was not working

Comment: works fine for me.. whats the error for you?

Comment: internal server error. can you check and reformat your code

Comment: can i view your files somewhere? because this worked for me perfectly, Still I will again try to reformat

Comment: etc/di.xml Model/Resource/Modulename/Collection there is not anything like in this in di.xml

Comment: sorry about the confusion, by this i meant you need to update following files

Comment: etc/di.xml, another file to update Model/Resource/Modulename/Collection.php( add join in this file ) and one more file to upadte is Model/Resource/Modulename/Grid/Collection.php

Comment: I want to copy this file in my module and want to join and filter order grid but in this file in module-sales  module Model/ResourceModel/Order/Collection.php   There is no _initSelect method where I can apply my changes.

Comment: can you give me file path which I can copy in my module for sales order grid collection filter ?

Comment: please refer http://blog.sivaschenko.com/2016/05/magento-2-tutorial-add-column-to-sales.html.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having problems with [@Asrar](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/50597/asrar) solution just do this:

```
public function aroundGetReport(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $requestName
) {
    $result = $proceed($requestName);
    if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source_firsty') {
        if ($result instanceof $this->collection
        ) {
            $select = $this->collection->getSelect();
            $select->join(
                ["soi" => "sales_order_item"],
                'main_table.entity_id = soi.order_id',
                array('sku', 'name','item_id')
            )
                ->distinct();
            return $this->collection;
        }

    }
    return $result;
}
```

This seems to be working ok for me.