# M2.1.9- I used the method which joining table when adding column to order grid. But it is so slow and filter function disappear

Tags: magento2, join-table

There,

I used the method which joining table when adding new column to order grid. A new column is for company name and its information is from `sales_order_address`, not `sales_order`. I succeeded to bring company data but it is way too slow to load totally and filter function disappears (it appear again when i scroll down tho). Could you check my code,please?

### CODE

> app\code\Kbethos\CompanyColumn\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <plugin name="sales_order_additional_columns" type="Kbethos\CompanyColumn\Plugins\AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection" sortOrder="20" disabled="false" />
</type>
</config>
```

> app\code\Kbethos\CompanyColumn\Plugins\AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection.php

```
<?php namespace Kbethos\CompanyColumn\Plugins;

use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as SalesOrderGridCollection;

class AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection
{
    private $messageManager;
    private $collection;

    public function __construct(MessageManager $messageManager,
        SalesOrderGridCollection $collection
    ) {

        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public function aroundGetReport(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $requestName
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($requestName);

        if ($requestName === "sales_order_grid_data_source") {
            $select = $result->getSelect();

            $select->join(
                ["soa" => "sales_order_address"],
                'main_table.entity_id = soa.parent_id AND soa.address_type="shipping"',
                array('company')
            )
                ->distinct();
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

> app\code\Kbethos\CompanyColumn\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <columns name="sales_order_columns">

        <!-- sales_order_address company -->
        <column name="company">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">right</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <!--<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>-->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

### ISSUES

My Problem is

1. It spent a huge of times to bring company information totally because our order items counts 216,894 right away and it will be larger in the future. So my question is that there is another way to bring an information under the database table whose prefix is `sales_`,not `sales_order` table
2. After adding my module, the filtering function disappear. i mean my module makes the layout crushed. How can i handle this problem? 
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ad.2
You must add *sequence* field into *module* field in module.xml file.

```
<sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales" />
</sequence>
```