# Filter a custom attribute in Sales Order Grid

Tags: magento2, sales-order

Following this answer: [How to join order grid collection to custom table in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91807/how-to-join-order-grid-collection-to-custom-table-in-magento2/159691) I'm able to join the order custom attribute and show it in the column, the error comes with the filter when applied:

> INNER JOIN `mgnt_sales_order` AS `so` ON main_table.entity_id = so.entity_id WHERE (`custom_attribute` LIKE '%testing the filter%')
>
> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'custom_attribute' in where clause is ambiguous

This is because the field is actually in the `sales_order` table and not `sales_order_grid`

*view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml*

```
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <column name="custom_attribute">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Attribute</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

*Plugins/AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection.php*

```
<?php namespace Vendor\Module\Plugins;

use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as SalesOrderGridCollection;

class AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection
{
    private $messageManager;
    private $collection;

    public function __construct(MessageManager $messageManager,
        SalesOrderGridCollection $collection
    ) {

        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public function aroundGetReport(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $requestName
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($requestName);
        
        $tableSalesOrder = $this->collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order');

        if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
            if ($result instanceof $this->collection) 
            {
                $select = $this->collection->getSelect();

                $select->join(
                    ["so" => $tableSalesOrder],
                    'main_table.entity_id = so.entity_id',
                    array('so.custom_attribute')
                )
                    ->distinct();
            }

        }
        return $this->collection;
    }
}
```

**Goal:** Filter the orders grid by a custom attribute of the order.

Unfortunally the solution with the plugin above creates other problems in the order view.. that's why I'm looking for other solutions

Comment: what you want actually still not getting you can you please explain

Comment: @RutveeSojitra being able to filter the orders grid by a custom attribute, which is joined from the sales_order table.. right now it shows the query error wrote above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. seems like I found a workaround, very ugly.
I persist the custom attribute in the `sales_order_grid` table when I retrieve the column value, through a raw PDO prepared statement query..

> Ui/component/Listing/Column/CustomAttribute.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;


class CustomAttribute extends Column
{
  protected $_orderRepository;
  protected $_searchCriteria;

  public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context, 
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, 
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
  ) {
    $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
    $this->resource = $resource;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);

    $this->tableSalesOrderGrid = $this->resource->getTableName("sales_order_grid");
  }

  public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
  {
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
      $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();

      foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {

        $columnName = $this->getData('name');
        $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
        $attrValue = $order->getData($columnName);
        $item[$columnName] = $attrValue;

        if ($columnName == "custom_attribute") {
          $sql = "UPDATE " . $this->tableSalesOrderGrid . " SET custom_attribute = :VALUE WHERE entity_id = " . $item["entity_id"];
          $binds = [
            "VALUE" => $attrValue
          ];
          $connection->query($sql, $binds);
        }

      }
    }

    return $dataSource;
  }
}
```

This class is specified in the `ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml` file