# magento 2.3 use core tables to custom module grid

Tags: magento2.3, ui-grid

I have a custom module with a custom table and I've created a ui component grid to show its data in Magento backend. This works fine.

Now I need a second admin grid were to show a collection of order items. The problem is that I'm not able to populate the grid with the records from the `sales_order_item` table.

As a temporary workaround, I created a custom DataProvider to fetch the data from the order item collection interface but this way I had to rewrite all the filters and sorting methods. This way the second grid works as intended: it shows the filtered collection of order items correctly.

Still, I think it would be more efficient to just keep the original Magento functionality but I don't know how to bind the core sales order item table to my custom grid.

I simply tried to create a new `Model/ResourceModel/Collection` that links to the core table but that doesn't work, I get the error: `"class xx/Grid/Collection does not exists".` My code:

> - Vendor/Module/Model/Name.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Name as ResourceModel;

class Name extends AbstractModel
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init(ResourceModel::class);
    }

}
```

> - Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Name.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Name extends AbstractDb
{
    const TABLENAME = "sales_order_item";
    const KEY_ID = 'item_id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(self::TABLENAME, self::KEY_ID);
    }

}
```

> - Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Name/Collection.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Name;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Vendor\Module\Model\Name as Model;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Name as ResourceModel;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(Model::class, ResourceModel::class);
    }
}
```

> - Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Name\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sales_order_item</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Name</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="vendor_module_name_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Name\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

As I said, this doesn't work, when I load the page I get the error `"Class Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Name\Grid\Collection does not exist".` So how can I link my custom grid to the core `sales_order_item` table?

Comment: please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91807/how-to-join-order-grid-collection-to-custom-table-in-magento2/159691#159691 . It might be helpful in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the link. If I understood the post correctly, those examples allow you to join a core table to your custom table. But my second grid has no custom table, it only needs the data in the core table.

So I need to be able to call the sales order item collection to populate my custom grid

Comment: I am also stuck in the same scenario. I want to achieve the same result. How to make a Custom Model, Resource Model and a Collection for the "sales_order_items" table. Which is Magento Core Database Table. No Help i found anywhere.