# Magento 2 : How to add country_id column in sales order grid

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, sales-order, order-grid

I want to add/filter country_id column of shipping address in sales order grid.

I refer below link which is useful to display regoin_id.

By doing same I am able to add country id as a column but when I perform filter on that ambiguous error is generated.

> https://www.mageworx.com/blog/how-to-add-column-with-filter-to-magento-2-orders-grid/

[image]

Please check below code, I changed for country id :

```
public function afterGetReport($subject, $collection, $requestName)
{
    if ($requestName !== 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
        return $collection;
    }

    if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_grid')) {
        try {
             $orderAddressTableName           = $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_address');
            $directoryCountryRegionTableName = $collection->getResource()->getTable('directory_country_region');
             $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['soat' => $orderAddressTableName],
                'soat.parent_id = main_table.entity_id AND soat.address_type = \'shipping\'',
                ['telephone']
            );
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['dcrt' => $directoryCountryRegionTableName],
                'soat.region_id = dcrt.region_id',
                ['code']
            );
            
             $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['dcrt' => $directoryCountryRegionTableName],
                'soat.country_id = dcrt.country_id',
                ['country_id']
            );
        } catch (\Zend_Db_Select_Exception $selectException) {
            // Do nothing in that case
            $this->logger->log(100, $selectException);
        }
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

di.xml

```
   <column name="country_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country Id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">65</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Comment: Did you get any further with this?

Answer (score 1):

If it is no collection

change

```
return $collection;
```

to

```
return $result
```

Full working code for country_id would be as follows

```
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as SalesOrderGridCollection;

class AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection
{
    private $messageManager;
    private $collection;

    public function __construct(MessageManager $messageManager,
                                SalesOrderGridCollection $collection
    ) {

        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public function aroundGetReport(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $requestName
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($requestName);


        if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
            if ($result instanceof $this->collection
            ) {
                $select = $this->collection->getSelect();

                $select->join(
                    ["soa" => "sales_order_address"],
                    'main_table.entity_id = soa.parent_id AND soa.address_type="shipping"',
                    array('country_id')
                )
                    ->distinct();
                return $this->collection;
            }

        }
        return $result;
    }



}
```