# how to join sales_order_address table with sales collection factory

Tags: magento2, order-grid, join-table

If I already have the function (last 30 minutes order cron job)below to get sales_order_grid table data, how can I join table to get sales_order_address table and get country_id, city and postal_code?

```
public function getSalesOrderGrid()
{
    try {
        $itemData = $this->salesCollectionFactory->create();
        $currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // Y-m-d h:i:s
        $newDate = strtotime('-30 MINUTE', strtotime($currentDate));
        $newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newDate);

        $itemData->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', ['gteq' => $newDate]);
        $itemData->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', ['lteq' => $currentDate]);
        $itemData->load();

        return $itemData;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the below code.

```
public function getSalesOrderGrid()
{
    try {
        $itemData = $this->salesCollectionFactory->create();
        $currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // Y-m-d h:i:s
        $newDate = strtotime('-30 MINUTE', strtotime($currentDate));
        $newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newDate);

        $itemData->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', ['gteq' => $newDate]);
        $itemData->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', ['lteq' => $currentDate]);
        /* join with sales order address table */
        $itemData->getSelect()
        ->join(
            ["soa" => "sales_order_address"],
            'main_table.entity_id = soa.parent_id',
            array('country_id', 'city', 'postal_code')
        )
        ->where(
        'soa.address_type=?',
        'billing');
        $itemData->load();

        return $itemData;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

[For more details you can Refer below source code link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91807/how-to-join-order-grid-collection-to-custom-table-in-magento2)

Comment: thanks for the input, however I hit another issue. since the sales_order_address table has 2 records for 1 order. 1 record is billing address and then other one is shipping address. If I want to get the billing address data. I found that there is a table called sales_order contain the billing address id and shipping address id. How can I get billing address data from my above function?

Comment: Updated my answer with distinct in query.

Comment: thanks! I have a question by using distinct, how it define which is shipping address record and which is billing address record? without distinct, it should return both from the query

Comment: Now I have added the where condition to fetch billing address only. but you can change with shipping as well.

Comment: oh right! How come I miss that column! thankyou for your input!