# Magento 2: How to add Company column in Sales Order grid adminpanel

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, uicomponent

How to add Customer billing company Column inside Sales order grid in admin panel.

I want to add extra column inside sales order grid, how to do this in order grids.

Thanks.

Comment: try refer to this
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90850/how-to-add-custom-column-of-custom-table-field-or-module-to-sales-order-admin-gr

Comment: Here are detailed instructions on how to add column to sales order grid: http://www.sivaschenko.com/magento2-sales-order-grid-column/